# .NetCore.App Runtime pack issue after upgrading VS on build server

Tags: .net-core

I wonder if anybody knows the recommended and most economical solution for this problem.

Our builds were working fine and the `deps.json` file was producing this output:
`runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x86/3.1.3`

After VS upgrade, now getting this in the build ouput `deps.json` file:
`runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x86/3.1.9`

Have tried putting this in the `.csproj` file to no avail:
`<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>3.1.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>`

Does anybody know what is the best way / practise to resolve this?